# Tensorflow installation error on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

I am just about to install tensorflow to Anaconda environment, but I have some problems. Once I put the following command

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl
```

I get the error message: tensorflow_gpu_1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Then I upgraded pip with this command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

But nothing happened. I have python 3.5.2 and Anaconda 4.2.0 (64 bit).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install with `amd64` instead of `x86_64`:

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: @Dean Fenster can you provide attention on my  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553860/tensorflow-install-failed-inside-anaconda-in-windows-machine) for a second. If you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on pip install.  Tried the above and lots of files downloaded.
But at the end got this error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\oskars~1.rie\appdata\local\temp\pip-crhbnr-build\setup.py