# Tensorflow install failed inside Anaconda in Windows Machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, tensorboard

Well, I am so tired of trying to install `Tensorflow` in `Anaconda`, I have installed anaconda successfully, but when I am going to install form this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), Anaconda installation on Step 4, I am seeing some exception. 
I have executed this line of command

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl
```

However it's terminating showing a red single line exception. [image: red line]

Later I have searched for some solution on here and there. I have found some solution too. In this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622613/tensorflow-installation-error-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform) is done for only `MAC OX` and `Linux` only, not for `Windows`. Later I found somewhere to use the python version 2.7 so I have downgraded the `Python` in lower version, however it was same. But this time I can able to to execute the MAC OX command successfully and in my prompt it shows that install successful. But when I had gone to import `Tensorflow` then again an error is threading, like this [image]

I have also found the some other solutions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130489/installing-tensorflow-with-anaconda-in-windows) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634008/how-to-install-tensorflow), however none of them are done in which process I'm approaching. I am in a quiet confusion what kind of error or exception it is? And how do I overcome it?

Update: 
Tensorflow has been installed successfully from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474666/tensorflow-installation-error-on-windows-7?rq=1), Now a different problem is being facing. When I am going to import tensorflow in my workspace it providing this error.  [image][image]

Comment: Windows version works only for 3.5 version

Comment: Yeah. I have tried in 3.5 version at first. Later I have tried 2.7 too.

Comment: Mainly my exception is occurring when I am trying to install tensorflow from the google apis.

Comment: Try this: http://bottomstack.com/installing-tensorflow-windows-and-visual-studio/

Comment: Shall I run it's commands in conda environment?? will it be okay?? Actually I am not familiar with CUDA, So I was expecting a solution on Anaconda.

Comment: Haven't tried it in anaconda, but ideally it should work. I installed Python from the original distribution though.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/zW0fk) it's installed succesfully, but tensorflow is not working like previously. like this [link](http://imgur.com/a/9lkjV)

Comment: In your first line of code you are installing the cpu version, but in the command line you are installing the GPU version ... which one do you want?

Comment: I have tried both. None of them were working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it cannot find the required CUDA libraries. Did you install the CUDA Toolkit 8.0 and cuDNN 5.1?

You will have to install the CUDA Toolkit 8.0 e.g. from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) and the cuDNN package from e.g. [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) and then put the `cuDNN-installation-path/win10/bin` on your path (depending on your windows version of course)

Also the following two posts might help you out:

- [On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso)
- [TensorFlow on Windows: "Couldn't open CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007279/tensorflow-on-windows-couldnt-open-cuda-library-cudnn64-5-dll)

Comment: Do I need to install `bazel` now??

Comment: ups, sorry, I was mistaken ... it looks like it can't find the CUDA libraries, see my Edit.